# iterm2 issue : create new tab with same path of previous current tab BUT 2 tabs are clones and not indepedent

Tags: terminal, tabs, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

I have switched from default terminal on MacOS Mojave to `iterm2`. I have an issue about the opening of a new tab from the current tab.

Indeed, I would like to be in the same path than the previous current tab.

For this, I did the classical procedure, i.e to go to `iterm2` preferences and `Profile` and choose `Reuse previous session's directory` for new tab :

[image]

Then, the issue is that once tab opened, all the other tabs are affected and change from their old path to the path of the new tab:  I don't understand what happens and which option to use to  prevent this behavior.

1. Every tab is the same than the others: if I do a `cd ~/foo/`, then the other tabs will go into `foo`directory.
2. Result worse: if I edit with `vim` a file in one tab, if I do a `cd ~/foo/` in another tab, then the tab associated to the edited file disappears is clearing this edition and shows the same windows than the tab where I did `cd ~/foo/`: very strange.

I want to keep all the current path  for all  others tabs except for the new one which must be the  same than the previous one from which I do a CMD+T.

I saw on different forums this issue sometimes occurs.

### Update 1

From what I have seen, it seems that I have to find a way to create a new session when I do the shortcut CMD+T to get another tab independent from the current one (from which I do CMD+T).

But unfortunately, I didn't find how to create a new session in `iTerm2` (inside the `iTerm2 - Preferences - profile`, I could execute a script that creates this new session). From the moment, you can see the command (`/bin/bash` that I launch when I open a new tab:

[image: command /bin/bash launched for new tab]

I tried also to build the binary `iTerm2` from the sources but issue remains.

### Update 2

I tried to use a little apple script to force a new session to be created from current window:

```
tell application "iTerm2"
    tell current window
        create tab with profile "Terminology2"
    end tell
end tell
```

(where Terminology2 is a duplicate of profile Terminology (default profile).

But always the same issue, the 2 tabs are not independent: each command in one of 2 is executed on the another one.

### Update 3

I keep on trying a solution: for this I removed the `macport` package and hidden files and directory `~/.iTerm2/`.

So I downloaded the `iTerm2 zip` archive from iTerm2 official website.

Here's a screen capture of my profile :

[image: profile]

Is `shortcut key` necessary in this profile to open new tabs : the issue seems to come from this option since it may not concern the shortcut for a new tab ? CMD+T is already a shortcut for opening an independent tab, isn't it ?

### Update 4

**Solution finally found**. Coming from classic MacOS terminal, I was used to do a shortcut CMD+Shift+-> or CMD+Shift+<- to change of tab.

But by chance, I tried simply the shortcut CMD+-> or CMD+<- and so was able to switch between 2 tabs independent.

So this was an error of beginner into iTerm2's world since I was used to apply old classical shortcut of default terminal.

If someone else makes the same mistake, they will know that it is just a configuration issue of shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Do you see the all-pane input icon in the upper right?
Command-Shift-I to toggle it. (that is a capital i)

Comment: this doesn't work, whatever I  toggle it or  not when I do a CMD+T, all the new tabs are clones.

Comment: Only other thing I could think to try is clearing all the setting: `defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2` ...if that doesn't change the behavior back to default then I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried your command but this doesn't change anything, same cloning between the 2 tabs ... I have just upgraded from Mojave to Catalina and the bug remains : Does this bug occur often on recent MacOS Macbook version ? Regards

Comment: I've also upgraded to Catalina. Been using iTerm/iTerm2 on different OSX versions for a long time, never had this issue. In your settings you're executing /bin/bash instead of just using a login shell, which is why I recommended clearing your settings back to default. 
I still think there must be some setting or script causing this and not the application itself, but if it's affecting default settings I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your remark ... How can I totally clean up the installation of iTerm2 ? Are there hidden files to remove (like ~/.iterm2) ? Even by doing a `sudo port uninstall iterm2`, I can still launch iTerm2, I don't understand why the executable is not removed (I remenber to have donwloaded a zip file from official iTerm2 website)... If you had another suggestions ?

Comment: That line of code I gave you before is from the iTerm documentation to remove all settings, deleting the application would be the only other step to clean it totally. Why are you installing with ports rather than the prepackaged? https://iterm2.com/downloads/stable/iTerm2-3_3_6.zip

Comment: It's possible you've installed multiple versions and now have setting affected by both

Comment: yes, I should have mixed multiple versions, I am going to clean `macport` package and associated config files and try to setup the .zip archive, I keep you informed, Regards

Comment: I show you a screen capture of the `profile section`and the necessity or not to set a CMD+T shortcut to open a new tab on this `profile section`. I have also change the `/bin/bash` to `login shell` option. It seems that `iTerm2` has already this shortcut integrated by default. I tried to set another shortcut like CMD+A or other nut issue remains.

Answer (score 2):

The OP already answered the question in **Update 4**, but in case anyone jumps right to the answers, the solution was to update the `Key Mappings` and create two new entries - `CMD+SHIFT+LEFT` & `CMD+SHIFT+RIGHT` - with assigned actions of `Previous Tab` and `Next Tab`, respectively.

These entries can be created in `Preferences -> ${Your Profile} -> Keys`, and then clicking on the `+` icon near the `Presets...` button.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have Broadcasting enabled. To check:

Toolbar > Shell > Broadcast Input > Send input to current Session Only

Comment: Do you use iTerm2 on your macOS ? and if yes, did you manage to disable the broadcast input ? I mean no clone new tab opened with CMD+T ?

Comment: Yes I use new tabs and splits a ton, not having the issue you're describing. Do you have any screen or tmux configs in your .bash_profile by any chance? The other difference in my settings is that I use login shell, not /bin/bash

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain me please how to open a new tab not cloned with screen  or tmux ? I mean to find an alternative to my issue.

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out ? If not I'll take another look. Also curious to know what is causing that behavior.

Comment: yes, I managed to do what I wanted. You can see the solution into my **UPDATE4**